# Сьемка видео в браузере телефона под андроид на Javascript

Tags: javascript

Можно ли с браузера мобильного телефона снимать видео со звуком? Как будто в приложении. А также микрофон

Comment: https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/media/recording-video